# How to add text from a form to parameter of a url in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to add the text entered by user in search box to append the url
eg file/search/{filename} here filename is entered by user in the search box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need javascript or an extra step in laravel.

In Laravel you can:

1. route to get the form var
2. in controller (or directly in route), get vars passed from the form
3. process it and redirect the url you want
4. route to search with string

Just for sample:

```
Route::post('search', ['as' => 'formsearch', function(){
    //better do this in controller
    $file = Request\Request::input('file');
    return Redirect::route('search', [$file]);
});
Route::get('search/{$file}', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@dosearch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

First change your post method to the following

```
Route::post('search',function()
{
    $filename = Input::get('filename_from_input_box');
   return Redirect::to('search/'.$filename);
});
```

And Your get method to...

```
Route::get('search/{filename}',function($filename)
{
    ///Do your code here to search
});
```

Hope you will find it helpful.